# Django manytomany relationship on recipe-meal

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

So I have this two models, which is Recipe and Meal. For example I want to get the Chicken Pasta meal for chicken and pasta ingredients. how do I do that?

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    mealId = models.ForeignKey('meal.Meal',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='meal')
    ingredientId=models.ManyToManyField('ingredient.Ingredient')
    amountId=models.ManyToManyField('amount.Amount')


class Meal(models.Model):
    mealName=models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="Meal name")
    desc=RichTextField()
    img=models.ImageField(blank=True)
    categoryId=models.ManyToManyField('category.Category')
```

Comment: What field in Ingredient model do you use for search? Can Reciple of the Chicken Pasta have not only chicken and pasta ingredients?

Comment: You have posted `Meal` which has no obvious connection to your question (you want the chicken and pasta *recipe*, right?). And you haven't posted `Ingredient`, which would be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want search ingredients by **name** field of your **Ingredient** model, as "chicken", "pasta" and your Reciple of the Chicken Pasta can contain additional ingredients, for example: "chicken", "pasta", "salt", "sauce". Then you can do it this way:

```
# put here import your models
names_for_search = [
        "chicken",
        "pasta"
    ]
queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
for name in names_for_search:
    queryset = queryset.filter(ingredientId__name__in=[name])
result_reciple = queryset.first()
if result_reciple is not None:
    result_meal = result_reciple.mealId
```

Comment: I think you can remove the for loop and use `queryset=queryset.filter(ingredientId__name__in=names_for_search)`

Comment: @ruddra Without the loop, you select Recipes with *either one* of the ingredients in the list.

Comment: Yes, you right. But in that case, I think you need to remove `__in`, because as far as I know `__in` works in list.

Comment: @ruddra Yes, `__in` works in list, a forgot about bracket